# how to resolve mongoDB C++ results returned by find method?

Tags: c++, mongodb

In mongoDB database iPodia and collection OVS_DETAILS, I have a record as

> ```
> { 
>
> "_id" : 
>     ObjectId("57ab14508b16c9557dcfa316"), 
>
>     "dpid" : "202481588545212", "mac" : "b8:27:eb:28:a6:bc", 
>
>     "extranet_gateway_mac" : "f0:b4:29:52:8f:b6", 
>
>     "extranet_gateway_ip" : "192.168.31.1", 
>
>     "extranet_public_ip" : "59.66.214.24", 
>
>     "extranet_private_ip" : "192.168.31.118",
>
>     "extranet_netmask" : "255.255.255.0", 
>
>     "intranet_cidr_prefix" : 22020096, 
>
>     "intranet_cidr_length" : 29, "persist" : 0, 
>
>     "timestamp" : 1470187766 
>
> }
> ```

```
auto cursor = db["OVS_DETAILS"].find({filter_builder.view});
for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
    std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
}
```

How can I resolve the result? For example, get the value with key "persist".

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the `bsoncxx::document::view` from the cursor, you can access an element view with the `[]` operator (but keep in mind that's a linear search each time).  Given an element view, you can check the type and extract a value of interest:

```
bsoncxx::document::element element = doc["mac"];
if(element.type() != bsoncxx::type::k_utf8) {
    // Error
}
std::string mac = element.get_utf8().value.to_string();
```

For 'persist', you probably want to check the type for an integer type and then extract it with one of the `get_XXX` methods for integers.  See the [element documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/cxx11/current/classbsoncxx_1_1document_1_1element.html) for more details.